# How to scrape AEM forms?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, aem

I'm trying to figure out how to scrape dynamic AEM sign-in forms using python.

The thing is I've been trying to figure out which module would be best to use for a sign-in form field that dynamically pops up over a webpage.

I've been told Selenium is a good choice, but so is BeautifulSoup.

Any pointers to which one would be best to use for dynamically scraping these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Selenium as it provides complete browser interface and is mostly used for automation. Selenium will make it more easy to implement and most importantly maintain.